# Trying to create simple table from array of objects with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple table with jQuery by looping through an array of objects but get this message in the console:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'people[i].lastName')
```

It works if I define the specific object (i.e. John.lastName) but not using the `array[i]`, am I doing something wrong?

```
var person = function(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName || "Anonymous";
    this.lastName = lastName || "Anonymous";
    };

    var John = new person("John", "Walter");
    var Bob = new person("Bob", "Stevens");
    var Gerry = new person("Gerry", "Cricket");
    var Frank = new person("Frank", "Bloom");

    var people = [John, Bob, Gerry, Frank];

    for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("<table><tr><td>" + people[i].lastName + "</td></tr></table>");
    });

    };
```

Comment: The given code works. http://jsfiddle.net/qYb66/ What are you not telling us? Also not sure why you have `$(document).ready(function() {` inside of the foreach loop.

Comment: You also create 4 tables instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can't put a $(document).ready within a for loop. Put your function inside the document.ready and your code works fine. To Add a table before the for loop and the /table 
after the for loop to prevent making each row in the array a table.

     $(document).ready(function()
  {
var person = function(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName || "Anonymous";
    this.lastName = lastName || "Anonymous";
    };

    var John = new person("John", "Walter");
    var Bob = new person("Bob", "Stevens");
    var Gerry = new person("Gerry", "Cricket");
    var Frank = new person("Frank", "Bloom");

    var people = [John, Bob, Gerry, Frank];
        $("body").append("<table>");

    for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
console.log(people[i]);

   $("table").append("<tr><td>" + people[i].lastName + "</td></tr>");

    };
    $("<table>").append("</table>");
    });
```

Comment: It's still creating 4 tables instead of one though

Comment: I updated the example to make only one table. Thanks!